# Qt 4: Move window without title bar

Tags: qt, qt4, window, draggable, popupwindow

I have a `Qt::Popup` flagged window (which does not have a title bar and close etc buttons) and would like to move by dragging\clicking on the non-title bar area....

On Win32, the solution could be [WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645620%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but my requirement is crossplatform.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this to move the window manually:

```
void PopupWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event){
    mpos = event->pos();
}

void PopupWindow::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event){
    if (event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) {
        QPoint diff = event->pos() - mpos;
        QPoint newpos = this->pos() + diff;

        this->move(newpos);
    }
}
```

And declare `QPoint mpos` somewhere.

Answer (score 6):

```
if (event->buttons() && Qt::LeftButton) {
```

this condition is true for every mouse button

maybe you kept in mind this

```
if (event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) {
```