# What's the suitable widget in PyQt to create a floating widget on the desktop?

Tags: python, pyqt4

I'd like to create something very alike to Rainlendar with python.
Currently I'm using PyQt for GUI, but there doesn't seem to be a widget type that can directly display something like that, specifically I mean:

1. No edge displayed, incuding buttons on the top right corner.
2. No corresponding bar in the task bar.
3. Able to display a icon in the icon area in the bottom right corner of the desktop.

Is there any widget capable of this ?
Or can I do some modification to any existing widget to achieve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Have a look at the docs for [QWidget.setWindowFlags](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qwidget.html#windowFlags-prop). In particular, when coupled with [Qt.FramelessWindowHint](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qt.html#WindowType-enum) it should be borderless and buttonless.
2. Another task for setWindowFlags — setting it to Qt.Tool stops the task bar entry. So combined with the above, you want `window.setWindowFlags(Qt.Tool | Qt.FramelessWindowHint)`
3. See the docs for [QSystemTrayIcon](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qsystemtrayicon.html)

Comment: Without the title bar, how can I drag the window to move around ?

Comment: That has been addressed many times, e.g. see this question: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513060/qt-4-move-window-without-title-bar