# Is there any drag - move method in Qt5?

Tags: c#, qt, window, drag, qt5

I remember that in C# there is a method called `DragMove()` that allows to drag a window by clicking on the selected area.

Example (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7418629/1420197) answer):

```
private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
        this.DragMove();
}
```

Is there any function like this in Qt world?

I know that [a solution would be to listen for `mousePressEvent` and `mouseMoveEvent`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5514580/1420197) but I just want to know if there is native method that would allow to drag the winodw on the screen just calling it, like in C# `this.DragMove()`.

Also, it needs to be cross-platform...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no function like what you refer to in Qt. Listening for mouse events is simple, and would be considered idiomatic in Qt.

If you want the widget to be draggable by pressing anywhere between controls, just implement those events in the base event. Any area not covered by controls will be "draggable".

Comment: Can you add an example, please?